# Custom annotation cucumber jvm

Tags: java, cucumber

Is there a way to add custom annotations for step methods in cucumber? For example, I would like to have something like this,

```
@CustomAnnotation
@When("blabla")
{
}
```

something similar to TestNG's IInvokeMethodListener. Does cucumber provide a hook for that?

Comment: You can tag scenarios and features: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Answer (score 0):

*Interface IInvokedMethodListener - A listener that gets invoked before and after a method is invoked by TestNG. This listener will only be invoked for configuration and test methods.*

If you want before and after use cucumber [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks).

**Update**

For java, you can look [here](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/).